# Cannot get Datatables editor to initialize

Tags: javascript, datatable

I am working on a page where an xlsx file is uploaded, parsed into an array of objects (each row is an object) and then populated into a Data Table. I want to be able to edit the data in the table before i click another button and send it to the database. Cannot get the editing to work though. I have tried loads of different ways that I found online of initializing the editor but none work for me.

If I get rid of the editor code, a normal Data Table works fine, but as of now I get the error:

`Cannot read property Editor of undefuned`

Here is the code and how I populate the Data Table

```
$(function() {
    let session = '<?=json_encode($_SESSION)?>';
    //console.log(session);

     var editor = new $.fn.dataTabe.Editor({
         table: '#datatable'
     });

    var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
    table
        .order( [ 3, 'asc' ] ).page.len( 10 )
        .draw();
    });

    let fileIn;
    let resultArray;
    let finalArray = new Array;

    document.getElementById('getFile').addEventListener('click', () => {
        fileIn = document.getElementById('my_file_input').files[0];
        console.log(fileIn);
        parseExcel(fileIn);
        setTimeout(() => {
            resultArray.forEach((arr) => {
                let company = (arr.company) ? arr.company : null;
                let category = (arr.category) ? arr.category : null;
                let pcs_no = (arr.pcs_no) ? arr.pcs_no : null;
                let product_name = (arr.product_name) ? arr.product_name : null;
                let min_range_rate = (arr.min_range_rate) ? arr.min_range_rate : null;
                let max_range_rate = (arr.max_range_rate) ? arr.max_range_rate : null;
                let max_total_rate_per_ha = (arr.max_total_rate_per_ha) ? arr.max_total_rate_per_ha : null;
                let measure_unit = (arr.measure_unit) ? arr.measure_unit : null;
                let range_notes = (arr.range_notes) ? arr.range_notes : null;
                let comment = (arr.comment) ? arr.comment : null;
                let crops;
                let pack_size;
                let chemical;

                if(arr.crops) {
                    if(arr.crops.includes(',')) {
                        crops = arr.crops.split(',');
                    } else {
                        crops = arr.crops;
                    }
                } else {
                    crops = null;
                }

                if(arr.pack_size) {
                    if(arr.pack_size.includes(',')) {
                        pack_size = arr.pack_size.split(',');
                    } else {
                        pack_size = arr.pack_size;
                    }
                } else {
                    pack_size = null;
                }

                if(arr.chemical) {
                    if(arr.chemical.includes(',')) {
                        chemical = arr.chemical.split(',');
                    } else {
                        chemical = arr.chemical;
                    }
                } else {
                    chemical = null;
                }

                let data = {
                    company,
                    category,
                    pcs_no,
                    product_name,
                    min_range_rate,
                    max_range_rate,
                    max_total_rate_per_ha,
                    measure_unit,
                    range_notes,
                    comment,
                    crops,
                    pack_size,
                    chemical
                }
                finalArray.push(data);
            }); 

            finalArray.forEach((arr) => {
                table.row.add([
                    arr.company,
                    arr.category,
                    arr.category,
                    arr.pcs_no,
                    arr.product_name,
                    arr.pack_size,
                    arr.chemical,
                    arr.min_range_rate,
                    arr.max_range_rate,
                    arr.max_total_rate_per_ha,
                    arr.measure_unit,
                    arr.range_notes,
                    arr.crops,
                    (arr.comment) ? arr.comment.trim() : null
                ]).draw(false)
            });
            console.log(finalArray);
        }, 3000);
    });
```

Comment: Show html - where you load DataTable plugin

Comment: @WiatroBosy `<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/plugins/DataTablesEditor/Editor-1.9.6/js/dataTables.editor.js"></script>`

Comment: Where exactly ? At the top of the page or at the bottom of the page?

Comment: @WiatroBosy Top, sorry

Comment: Move down of the page

Comment: @WiatroBosy Same result

Comment: You have loaded jQuery ? You must have https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js
../../extensions/Editor/js/dataTables.editor.min.js